# heap and stack in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory, heap-memory, stack-overflow

I have written a code in Eclipse which runs properly for small input values but as soon as my test cases increase in size, i get `OutOfMemoryException` or `StackOverFlow` error.

i tried to use `eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xmx1g` to make my heap go out to 1G but i still get the same error. and When i try 2G it says unable to start JVM.

so i m wondering if there is any ways at all for me to run this code. any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

EDIT:
this is where my heaps overflows. the input sample is too huge and causes the momory problem.

```
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] linevalue= (line.trim().split("\\s+"));
        int l= linevalue.length;
        dg.addNode(Long.parseLong(linevalue[0]));
        dg.addNode(Long.parseLong(linevalue[1]));
        dg.addEdge(Long.parseLong(linevalue[0]), Long.parseLong(linevalue[1]));

    }
```

In the other class the following code is present, here mGraph is a HashMap.

```
public boolean addNode(T node) {
    /* If the node already exists, don't do anything. */
    if (mGraph.containsKey(node))
        return false;

    /* Otherwise, add the node with an empty set of outgoing edges. */
    mGraph.put(node, new HashSet<T>());
    return true;
}


public void addEdge(T start, T dest) {
    /* Confirm both endpoints exist. */
    if (!mGraph.containsKey(start) || !mGraph.containsKey(dest))
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Both nodes must be in the graph.");

    /* Add the edge. */
    mGraph.get(start).add(dest);
}
```

Comment: Maybe by posting the code we could help you? Even better, post an SSCCE http://sscce.org

Comment: it's a start, but I don't see any real issue in that code. Maybe in addEdge or addNode, there is a recursion which quickly explodes? You should probably expose the whole classes.

Comment: made some more edits for better understanding. i hope this helps.

Comment: You can try increasing your stack size with -Xss option, but generally speaking, Guillaume Polet is right -- its difficult to exhaust a stack without having an uncontrolled recursion somewhere in your code. It may be a split() also, if your test lines are really-really long with a lot of white spaces.

Comment: the above given code is where i get a heap error. after this i perform some recursive DFS where i obtain a stackoverflow error.

Comment: So please, how large is your input, how many lines are we talking about? Millions?

Comment: over 5 millions i guess. but thanks anyways, the problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, you can set the size of the VM when you execute your code.

Go to `Run > Run configurations`. Then in the tab `Arguments`, put `-Xms1000m` under VM arguments.

Comment: and if i need to increase my stack too for the same run, how can i achieve that?

Comment: This has been addressed in this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408633/dynamically-increasing-java-heap-space tldr: You can't. You are limited by the initial VM size.

Comment: no what i actually meant was, i tried what you wrote for heap size, and it worked for me, but for the further recursive calls, my stack seemed insufficient. So my question to you was, can i set the stack size as well as the heap size at the same time for the VM in eclipse?
something like -Xms1000m, -Xss256m or of that sort.

Comment: i put the arguments in VM configuration as -Xms1000m -Xss64m and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on tskuzzy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181333/104950):

For heap,

```
-Xms -Xmx
```

For stack

```
-Xss
```

I would recommend `1g` for `Xmx` and `Xmx`, and `8m` for `-Xss`